# Google Maps Embed is messing with my font weight

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

When the google maps embed loads on my site, it takes all the font weight off of my font. I'm using open sans from google fonts at 400 and 700 weight. They intialize correctly and then google maps loads and it seems to drop all the font weights to 300. I think it has something to do with the roboto font that comes with the google maps api. Any help would be appreciated!